# RecyclerView(DiffUtil+ListAdapter) strange behavior after delete item

Tags: android

RecyclerView after delete any item lift bottom item up and redraw it at the same time.
It looks strange. How can i solve this problem?
(**how it looks
https://youtu.be/hKmNWwfxfzM !**)

```
val swipeHandler = object : SwipeToDeleteCallback(requireContext()) {
            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                viewModel.deleteNote(viewModel.noteListLiveData.value!![viewHolder.adapterPosition])
            }
        }
        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeHandler)
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.noteRecyclerView)
```

Use LiveData to update RV

```
viewModel.noteListLiveData.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner, { notes -> noteAdapter.submitList(notes) }
        )
```

DiffUtil and Adapter

```
 private inner class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<NoteEntity>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: NoteEntity, newItem: NoteEntity): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: NoteEntity, newItem: NoteEntity): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    private inner class NoteAdapter :
        ListAdapter<NoteEntity, NoteHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return super.getItemCount()
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteHolder {
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_note, parent, false)
            return NoteHolder(view)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bind(getItem(position))
        }
    }
```

I have been looking for a solution to the problem for a long time, but I could not understand what the reason is

*sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language*

Comment: Do you call `notifyItemRemoved()` on the adapter?

Comment: You have to delete that item from the dataset and submit it again on your `ListAdapter` instance

Comment: @Zain
no, because liveData observer notify RV about changes automatically

Comment: Yes, you're right just was in a doubt that was a potential reason of your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same exact problem and it was caused by using `wrap_content` for `RecyclerView` in your xml file.

Because you delete an item, the size of this view changes, and for a split second you can see this weird behaviour. To fix that, make sure that the `RecyclerView` occupies the whole screen - its height is set to `match_parent` and the container it is in is also set to `match_parent`.

Comment: Nice answer! .. Apart from the issue, using `wrap_content` for `RecyclerView` is not a good practice int terms of performance as it has new calculations for the entire list of the `RecyclerView` whenever adding/removing rows and this makes it lose its main feature for recycling views in this case

Comment: That is a valid point Zain. I am just wondering if `wrap_content` would cause trouble if `hasFixedSize` is set to true? From my understanding if `wrap_content` is a necessity in some case, setting this flag to true might help with performance issues caused by using `wrap_content`.

Comment: Nice catch indeed.. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709220/understanding-recyclerview-sethasfixedsize#59033210) has a clue, but I think you need to test it your self with a simple example, you could extend the `layoutManger` and debug it to see which methods can be called in either case

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Strange behavior was not caused by the adapter but by xml.
Height of the layout was set as wrap_content and after removing the item size of RV changed which caused the wrong behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For my case because i set adapter `setHasFixedSize(true)` its caused wrong behavior layout, change to `setHasFixedSize(false)` solved my case.